# Difference in call symputs for data _null_

Tags: sas

After inheriting some code from someone I noticed the following line,

```
data _null_;
    call symput("date",strip(put(compress(put(date(),YYMMDD10.),'-'),8.)));
run;
```

Why would I want to have the compress and strip? I find I get the same result by using

```
data _null_; 
    call symput('date2',put(date(),yymmddn8.)); 
run;

%put &date. &date2.;
```

The put statement yields the same result for both. Is there a specific reason why I would use a strip and compress for this operation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That specific one there's no real reason; the `put...yymmddn8.` doesn't give you any spaces.  I imagine that's a standard usage that someone just copy/pasted in - if you don't do the put it will give you spaces/etc.

`CALL SYMPUTX` is the real solution, anyway; it takes care of that for you :)